# fastify Serialization not working when using serzializationCompile

Tags: node.js, fastify

why required not works ?

Posts

```
let Items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'beitrag',
  }
];

export default Items;
```

```
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";
import Posts from '../posts';

const schema = {
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
      type: 'array',
        items: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            id: { type: 'number' },
            name: { type: 'string' },
            images: { 
              type: 'array',
              items: { image: { type: 'string' } }
            }
          },
          required: ['images']
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

const getPosts = (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  const serialize = reply.compileSerializationSchema(schema);
  const res = serialize({Posts});
  return res;
};

export {
  getPosts
};
```

And when I remove the name properity I do not get an error, so whats the reason to use compileSerizaltionSchema ? When I put the schema in the option field then it works. but I dont understand why this not works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your schema should be this instead:

```js
const schema = {
  response: {
    200: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          id: { type: 'number' },
          name: { type: 'string' },
          images: { 
            type: 'array',
            items: { image: { type: 'string' } }
          }
        },
        required: ['images']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at the example schema that is being used in fastify’s docs:

https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#compileserializationschemaschema-httpstatus-contenttype

As far as I know, I don't think you can use required in response schema.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).